# Looking for a D3 layout that functions like a tree, but begins and ends with one point

Tags: d3.js

I have been digging for a layout that would basically be similar to a tree but could also merge down into a single point.
`/‾B‾\___
A---C----\__D
 \_________/`

Sorry, my ascii skills are not great, but this graph would read:

A->B, A->C

B->D, C->D

A->D

Anyone have any ideas?  I was trying to use a force layout, but I couldn't figure out a way to make it not render in a circular pattern.  A tree would be the obvious choice, but I don't know how to collapse leaves back into nodes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://viz-js.com/bower_components/viz.js/viz-lite.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz/releases/download/v0.1.2/d3-graphviz.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph" style="text-align: center;"></div>
<script>

var dot = [
    'digraph G {',
    '    graph [rankdir=LR]',
    '    A -> B',
    '    A -> C',
    '    B -> D',
    '    C -> D',
    '    A -> D',
    '}',
 ].join('\n');

  d3.select("#graph").graphviz()
    .renderDot(dot);

</script>
```

Comment: That could be perfect!  So many hours trying to find something like that, I suppose that part of the problem is that I was looking strictly within D3.  Thanks!

The closest I got was with a Sankey: http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/c4544fa6ac1e903f56c6e6ff3a77920b

Comment: Glad to hear that :-). [d3-graphviz](https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz) **is** a [D3 plugin](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Plugins).

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)